# Populate ExpandableListView with data from SQLite in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I'm developing android app and want to fetch some result from sqlite db inside the app and display it in "ExpandableListView". here is what i want. The app will provide some list of disease(problem) for the user to select and when a specific disease is selected, a query will get executed based on the selected disease and fetch 'TradeName' from db that have the same 'ActiveIngredients'

The ActiveIngredient will be the PARENT list and all tradeNames that contain the active ingredient will be the CHILD list.

Previously i have used to normal ListView to populate the results but when the data is populated redundant ActiveIngredients will be listed.

The expected output should look like this.

[image]

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/                                              use this link... i think its helpfull to you .. before u start from ur source code jus try to example project

Comment: Revathi Manoharan Thanks for the link but in the link the parent and child items are populated manually. what i want is to populate them dynamical!

Comment: ok then how u differentiate parent and child items?

Comment: in sqlite u store your value by using key rite?

Comment: after getting active ingredient details store in one table named as table1 and then create another table named as table2 to add all tradeNames.then inside parent class get all storedata from table 1.inside child class get all store data from table 2.this is easiest way to handling dynamic outputs

Comment: This are the database tables in my sqldb :-                                                                                        CREATE TABLE "productList" ( `ID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `TradeName` TEXT, `ActiveIngridient` TEXT,  `ClassNo` INTEGER )

CREATE TABLE "pestList" ( `name` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`name`) )

CREATE TABLE "productUsage" ( `ID` INTEGER, `TrdNameID` INTEGER, `uFor` TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(`TrdNameID`) 
REFERENCES `productList`(`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(`uFor`) REFERENCES `pestList`(`name`), PRIMARY KEY(`ID`) )

Comment: i am thinking two queries. The first query will get all the active ingredients and the second query will return every tradeName that contain the active ingredients in the first query!

Comment: simply use `android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter`

Comment: okay! could you direct me to some link or just give me a hint!  Thanks!

Comment: see [ExpandableList2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList2.java)